# IndexOutOfBoundsException not thrown on adding element at invalid index in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

If we read the ArrayList documentation of add function [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29), clearly on adding element at invalid index throws IndexOutOfBoundsException. But why does the following code does not throw any exception?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        List cities = new ArrayList();
        cities.add("Atlanta");
        cities.add("Boston");

        try {
            for (int i = 10000000; i < cities.size(); i++){
                try {
                    cities.add(i, "+");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
                System.out.println(cities.size());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        System.out.println(cities);

    }
```

**Output:**

```
[Atlanta, Boston]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am currently using jdk 7 and running on intellij idea.

Comment: Because you don't add any element to the list except the first 2, that are printed out on the end.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++){

Comment: *"I am currently using jdk 7 and running on intellij idea."* IntelliJ IDEA has a great debugger built into it, with the ability to walk through the code step-by-step. It's almost like it was designed for figuring problems like this out or something...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your for loop is never entered, because 1000000 > cities.size() (which is 2).

Your code is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If i values start in 10000000, and you compare against 2 (cities.size()), it will never be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

3 things :

1. Your loop starts from `i= 10000000` and `cities.size()= 2`, so the condition `i<2` is never met and the loop is never entered.
2. `try{
          }catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }`

Never do this. Try to catch specific exceptions and **utilize** them! `e.printStackTrace()` basically just dumps your exception on the output stream and is lost.

3.
        System.out.println(cities);

This will use the default `toString()` implementation of an ArrayList. In this case it will be `[Atlanta, Boston]`